# Why SAX.writer(XML) and not CGI wrapper(HTML - {&OUT})

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to understand the difference between SAX.writer and CGI wrapper. I can't find any get started information, any suggested content OR video link it can be very appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [SAX writer](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/SAX-writer-object-handle.html?labelkey=product_openedge_126) is a set of language statements/elements that allow the creation of well-formed XML documents. This XML is output to the location specified by the [SET-OUTPUT-DESTINATION](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/abl-reference/page/SET-OUTPUT-DESTINATION-method.html#SET-OUTPUT-DESTINATION-method) method. Output destinations include streams (which might include a Classic WebSpeed stream (WEB-STREAM).

CGI wrapper is more of an approach, with a bunch of (internal) procedures that let you create a fully-formed HTTP response (and read from an incoming HTTP request). This approach should not be used for new web services, even though it still works. In newer version of OpenEdge the PASOE server provides what are known as WebHandlers, which replace the CGI wrapper approach.

The `{&OUT}` 'syntax' is really just a preprocessor that does something like `PUT UNFORMATTED STREAM WEB-STREAM` - you can see this if you compile your programs with the PREPROCESS option, or use the equivalent command in PDSOE (a right-click option).